# Innacurate Drawing When DropShadowFilter is Applied

Tags: actionscript-3

Basically, I am trying to create the illusion of 3 pieces of paper by programmatically drawing 3 white rectangles and having them slightly overlap then having a drop shadow on each. I then can tween to resize them.

If I have no filters on them it works fine and crisp. However, as soon as I add the filter they draw inaccurately, at some widths flash forgets to render one of the papers or often gets the X value wrong.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
   public function Paper():void{    
        a = new MovieClip();
        a.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        a.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,stage.stageHeight+100);


        b = new MovieClip();
        b.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        b.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,stage.stageHeight+100);


        c = new MovieClip();
        c.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        c.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,stage.stageHeight+100);
        this.addChild(c);
        this.addChild(b);
        this.addChild(a);

        b.filters = c.filters = a.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(5,90,0,0.6,10,10,1,4)];
        this.width = 800;

        b.y = 2;
        c.y = 4;
        this.y = 40;            
    };  

    public override function set width(value:Number):void{
        a.width = value;
        b.width = value+4;
        c.width = value+8;

        a.x = stage.stageWidth - a.width;
        b.x = a.x -2;
        c.x = a.x -4;       
    };

public function animateToWidth(target:Number):void{
        new GTween(this,0.5,{width:target},{ease:Sine.easeInOut});          
    };
```

I have tried rounding the value in the width setter in case it was caused by decimal values but it had no effect. Basically if I comment out the filters line of code it works perfectly but as soon I enable the filters all of a sudden flash can't position the rectangles properly

here are examples of two different widths, notice how in one each white rectangle has 2px between each step, where as in the other the bottom layer has 4 pixels while the middle layer only has 1px:

[image]
[image]

any ideas? I was hoping to avoid having to use image data but I am thinking I might have to just tween graphics.

thanks

Comment: May be the `GTween` causes problem ?

Comment: No, even if I don't even call animateToWidth it still has problems, depending on the width I set it draws differently.